# Facebook share article by image from website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook allows us to share our website page on facebook by implementing facebook graph og: structure on top of the page. But what if we want to have share button on actual images in the article. Let's say we have 5 images in article, and we have facebook share button near the image. Is there any tutorial how can implementation be achieved by sharing actual image and url of website, instead of preloaded facebook graph og: settings of the page?

Comment: You will need individual URLs for this, that return the appropriate OG meta data. So if you want to be able to share five different images individually, you need five such URLs, that embed one of those images each.

Comment: there are no urls. there is one url and five different images on that url. what i want to achieve is to when i click on image to share, i want to share that image but same url that i am currently on. so 5 different images same url. is that possible?

Comment: No, that is not possible.